# Broken packages on Codeblocks Installation

Tags: package-management, 18.04, code-blocks

I use Ubuntu 18.04, and I can't reinstall CodeBlocks, it does not work.
I installed Codeblocks 16.04 earlier but, then I uninstalled it, because I would like to use a new version like 17.12.Now, when I try to install it again, it shows me this error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codeblocks : Depends: codeblocks-common (= 16.01+dfsg-2.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can you help me with this? ....Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Codeblocks appears to be in the Ubuntu Repository.

Start by purging the installation you have now.

```
sudo apt purge codeblocks
```

Then reinstall:

```
sudo apt install codeblocks -y
```

To fix broken packages it is normally helpful to run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install -f
```

One after another.
In future to update it all you should need to do is run

```
sudo apt upgrade codeblocks
```